# Not Quite Invertible... But Close. Property of a Matrix.

Tags: matrices, vectors, operator-theory, matrix-equations

Let $b\in \mathbb{R}^d,A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be given.

If $A$ is invertible (with inverse $G$) then $GAw=w$, $w\in \mathbb{R}^d$. What properties of $A,b$ would we need to have to guarantee the existence of a $G$ such that

$$ G(b+Aw)=w ~~~~~~(1)$$

for any $w$? Say we allow $G$ above to be any operator ( not just a matrix ) could one exist for $(1)$ to hold? I mean I can just define the operator like this right?

Comment: In effect, you need a matrix $C$ such that $Cw=b$ and $A+C$ is invertible. I have a vague feeling that you've got more than enough freedom to achieve that.

Comment: Why would such a matrix help?

Comment: Wait... Is $b$ a fixed vector and $w$ just _any_ vector?

Comment: Yes this is the set up

Comment: @IvanNeretin is it impossible?

Comment: Too bad. Then what I said before is useless. But now I see it from another point. If a matrix is not invertible, it must send some vector to zero: $Aw=0$. Well, then $G(b+Aw)=\text{ just }Gb=w$ - that is, if we want (1) to hold for $w$. Now, what is going to happen with the vector $2w$?

Comment: good point, so it is impossible

Comment: So whatever $G$ I pick even nothing would work. Is there a way to construct some sort of approximation of this then?

Comment: What is it that you want to approximate, then? The condition (1) is out of reach; you must weaken it some way or another.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I will try and formulate an approximation of the statement $(1)$ which will hopefully be enough for me.

Comment: @IvanNeretin by a weaker statement I mean can we find an operator defined for all $h>0$ such that $G_h(b+Aw)=w+O(h)$, for all $w$.

Comment: My counterexample still stands. Plug $3w,\;4w\dots$

Comment: yeh your right.

Comment: @IvanNeretin wait not if O(h) depends on $w$?

Comment: Sorry you can ignore me, i'm loosing my mind a bit recently.

Comment: If you consider affine operators rather than linear operators, the question makes a lot of sense. An affine operator is one sending a vector $x \mapsto Ax + b$, for a fixed linear operator $A$ and vector $b$ - in other words it is a linear operator followed by a translation. Such an operator is bijective if and only if $A$ is bijective, and in that case the inverse operator is $x \mapsto A^{-1}(x - b) = A^{-1}x - A^{-1}b$, which is again an affine operator.

Comment: @Joppy so theres no hope if $A$ is a non invertible linear operator?

Comment: That's right - if $A$ is not invertible, then $x \mapsto Ax + b$ is not either, for any $b$. On the other hand, if $x \mapsto Ax + b$ is invertible, then $A$ is invertible and the function $G$ you are looking for must be the affine function $x \mapsto A^{-1}(x - b)$.

Comment: @Joppy this is very helpful :) do you have a reference for it?

Comment: No, I don't have a reference for it. It's clear that $x \mapsto x + b$ is a bijection for any $b$, so everything interesting is happening in the linear operator $A$. Affine transformations are fairly well-studied (they are just sidelined in courses usually, because all of the interesting stuff is contained in the linear operator). You can treat an affine transformation $x \mapsto Ax + b$ as a pair $(A, b)$ - we then have the composition rule $x \mapsto Ax + b \mapsto C(Ax + b) + d$ and hence $(C, d) \circ (A, b) = (CA, Cb + d)$ for example.

Answer (score 0):

Given $A$ and $b$, suppose that there exists a matrix $G$ such that, for any $w$:

$$G(b+Aw) = w ~~~~~~(1) .$$

This means that $G$ does not depend on $w$. Rather, it depends on $A$ and $b$ only. We may write:

$$G = G(A, b).$$

Equation (1) is equivalent to:

$$Gb = w - GAw \Rightarrow Gb = (I - GA)w, ~~~~~~(2)$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Suppose that $I-GA$ can be inverted, and let $M$ be the inverse. Again, $M$ depends only on $A$ and $b$, i.e.:

$$M = M(A,b).$$

Now, observe that multiplying both sides of equation (2) by $M$ one gets:

$$MGb = M(I-GA)w \Rightarrow MGb = w. ~~~~~~(3)$$

More precisely, equation (3) reads as:

$$M(A,b)G(A,b)b = w.$$

But this is a **contradiction**, since all factors on the left hand side does not depend on $w$! Hence, we must conclude that the matrix $G$ does not exist!

Comment: how can you assume $I-GA$ can be inverted. Also what if $G$ is not a matrix but some other nonlinear operator?

Comment: Why can't you assume $I-GA$? It is just a step in my proof. For other operator it would be more complicated.

Comment: Anyway, inversion of $I-GA$ is not so important. Indeed, if you look to equation (2), you observe that: $$G(A,b)b = (I - G(A,b)A)w,$$ which means that the left hand side does not depend of $w$, while the right one does! Again, you get a contradiction since this should work for any $w$! The conclusion is that $G \neq G(A,b).$ Instead, $G = G(A,b,w)$, so you need a different $G$ for each $w$.